# Fourier transform of vector valued function, would component wise approach suffice for this application?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have a vector valued function from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^m)$. I'd like to take a Fourier transform of this and do further computations, but in all my further computations, the only derivatives of this function I use are first order partial derivatives and never ask any questions on higher order derivatives. So, can I conveniently take component-wise Fourier transform without having any issues? ($m$ Fourier transforms of $m$ real valued functions)

Comment: What definition of the Fourier transform on vector functions are you using?  This is trivially true if it is defined component wise, which is the only case that I have ever seen.

Comment: @mathematician : Even I don't know. Thanks for the answer. I saw someone talking existence of some other definition, so I just wanted to be safe in my context. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34485/2987

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I have a similar problem which I've posted here: bit.ly/2JrFVkq

So is it okey to do the Fourier transform component-wise on a vector field?

Comment: @Ali : I believe so. I dont think any other definiton exists or necessary.